SEARCH formula in Excel returns #VALUE! error
I have picked this apart but continue to get a VALUE error in Excel.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  My sheet has a cell named "MaterialType" which is populated from a dropdown list of text values.  The values in the dropdown come from DataValidation referencing a range of cells in another worksheet (and those cells are actually populated with data from an online query of a web database of our products).  The cell is formatted "general" and some of the phrases (strings) in the list include the word "steel" and others do not.  The list of text includes spaces, parentheses, and lots of various words.  Most of the options do NOT contain this key phrase I am looking for.  Some examples are:

steel plate
angle iron (stainless steel)
aluminum
hardened-alloy

When I select one that DOES have the word steel, everything works as expected (it says "FOUND") but if I select any of the others, I get #VALUE! error.
=IF( SEARCH("steel",MaterialType)>0, "FOUND", "NOT FOUND" )


May be like this it will be =IF( 1-ISERR(SEARCH("steel",A1)), "FOUND", "NOT FOUND" )

SEARCH() function returns the positions of the search key word in a string, which is a number, when it doesn't find any it returns #VALUE! error, which is not greater than 0 therefore you are getting the FALSE argument as error instead of NOT FOUND

Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell B2
=IF( 1-ISERR(SEARCH("steel",A2)), "FOUND", "NOT FOUND" )


You can also use ISNUMBER() instead of 1-ISERR()
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("steel",A2)), "FOUND", "NOT FOUND" )


Reason Why You Are Getting An Error:
SEARCH() function returns the positions of the search key word in a string, which is a number, when it doesn't find any it returns #VALUE! error, which is not greater than 0 therefore you are getting the FALSE argument as error instead of NOT FOUND.


I prefer the ISNUMBER version of this...seems to more closely follow the logic.  Most importantly, both of these WORKED!  Thanks!

@techtheatre Thank you very much for sharing the valuable feedback, it literally helps to learn !!
